# Error when trying to pass a string into a json object c# - Current JsonReader item is not an object

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, console-application

I am trying to pass my variable query as a Json object. So I saw online that one way to do so is by doing `JObject.Parse()`. I attempted to do so, but when debugging I noticed that `.Parse()` would create a "{" at the beginning and a "}" at the end of the contents of the variable `query`. So I then attempted to remove the first "{" and last "}" inside of `query` but whenever I would hit the `JObject.Parse()` line, it would throw an exception saying:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 6.

So I then attempted to use the code after query, but this would still give me the same error when I hit the next line that consisted of `JObject.Parse()`:

```
if (query.Length > 2){ 
   query = query.Substring(1, s.Length-2)
}
```

So then I saw online that another way to get around this error is to use the following, but it would not remove the first "{" and last "}".

`query = query.TrimStart(new char[] { '{' }).TrimEnd(new char[] { '}' });`

**This is what my `query` consists of and what I tried to do to pass query as a json object:**

```
var query = "{\"size\": 1000,\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"should\":[ {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Information\" } }, {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Error\" } } ], " +
                    "\"filter\": [ { \"range\": { \"@timestamp\": { \"gte\": \"2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00\", \"lt\": \"2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00\" } } } ]," +
                    "\"minimum_should_match\": 1 } } }";


        query = query.TrimStart(new char[] { '{' }).TrimEnd(new char[] { '}' });
         
    /*    if (query.Length > 2){ 
           query = query.Substring(1, s.Length-2)
        }  */

        var jsonQuery = JObject.Parse(query);
```

**How would I go about resolving the issue I am having that `.Parse()` is adding an extra { at the beginning and } and at the end.**

Variable `Query` holds:

```
{"size": 1000,"query": {"bool": {"should":[ {"match": { "level": "Information" } }, {"match": { "level": "Error" } } ], "filter": [ { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00", "lt": "2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00" } } } ],"minimum_should_match": 1 } } }
```

Then jsonQuery holds:

```
{{  "size": 1000,  "query": {    "bool": {      "should": [        {          "match": {            "level": "Information"          }        },        {          "match": {            "level": "Error"          }        }      ],      "filter": [        {          "range": {            "@timestamp": {              "gte": "2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00",              "lt": "2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00"            }          }        }      ],      "minimum_should_match": 1    }  }}}
```

**If you look closely, .Parse() is adding a { at the beginning and adding another } at the end.**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. `JObject.Parse(query)` with the string defined as it is in your code sample correctly parses as a JSON object. What do you mean by 'extra' {, }? JSON objects must begin with an open parenthesis and end with a close parenthesis; that is what defines an object.

Comment: Please check the updated post. But if you look closely, `.Parse()` added another { at the beginning and another } at the end. I then went to the https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# to see if my json format was correct but it is not because it adds a { and a }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That double parentheses "issue" is just debugger display for `JObject` in Visual Studio. If you actually try to output `JObject` as a string, you'll get correct output.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = "{\"size\": 1000,\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"should\":[ {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Information\" } }, {\"match\": { \"level\": \"Error\" } } ], " +
            "\"filter\": [ { \"range\": { \"@timestamp\": { \"gte\": \"2021-07-26T07:58:45.304-05:00\", \"lt\": \"2021-07-26T08:58:45.305-05:00\" } } } ]," +
            "\"minimum_should_match\": 1 } } }";


    var jsonQuery = JObject.Parse(query);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonQuery); // all good!
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

On the side note, I think it would be easier for you to test Elasticsearch with `NEST` and `Elasticsearch.NET` nuget packages.

Comment: Oh I see, I was not aware that it was just on debug mode that you will see an extra "{". Thank you! Yes, I've done the same thing with NEST just wanted to try it out with the httpclient. Appreciate it! :)